# Windows XP 32-bit page fault (other OSes unaffected)

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, paging

The cause of this is unknown, as I performed a proper shutdown at the last time before this has occurred. I have attempted to boot into *Safe Mode* and twice used the *Last known good configuration* option. At the BSoD, it gives `0x0000007E (0xC0000005, 0x80631072, 0xB677C778)` for a third technical message. Removing the RAM sticks do not help, either. *Linux Lite Ubuntu* and the live OSes which I have used suffer no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur if a system thread generates an exception that the error handler does not catch. This exception can be caused by any of the following:

**If this issue occurs after the first restart during Windows Setup or after Setup is complete, the computer might not have sufficient hard disk space to run Windows XP.**

**The computer BIOS might be incompatible with Windows XP, or it might have to be updated.**

**The video adapter drivers might be incompatible with Windows XP.**

**A device driver or a system service might be damaged.**

**If the issue is associated with the Win32k.sys file, it might be caused by a third-party remote control program.**

The original KB-330182 article on the Microsoft Website is gone, [but I found this copy on the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150307000726/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330182)